# Can't import plot_model from keras.utils?

Tags: python, keras

When I run this line in my code,

`from keras.utils import plot_model`

I get the following:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_model' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)"
```

When I went to bed last night it was working. This morning it throws an error. What happened and what should I do? Thank you.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 26):

Try to import in the below format

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
```

This week I've had the same problem, with this import it works.

Answer (score 16):

This worked taking from [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model)

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=False, show_dtype=False,
show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB', expand_nested=False, dpi=96
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the second line. The import was good but the function was throwing errors.

Answer (score 5):

In the recent version of keras, `plot_model` function has been moved to `vis_utils` (visualization utilities) under the `utils` module. So, you can get your `plot_model` function to work using either of these imports:

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
```

The plot_model was previously in Keras.utils, but it can be fetched from vis.utils
Copy paste the above code, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

It is updated as:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```